# Different values of sizeof(datatype_pointer)/sizeof(datatype) for different datatypes, why?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

I declared the following struct in my C++ program:

```
    struct person {
        char name[10];      /* first name */
        char id[10];        /* ID number */
        off_t pos;      /* position in file, for demonstration */
    } people[] = {
        { "arnold", "123456789", 0 },
        { "miriam", "987654321", 10240 },
        { "joe",    "192837465", 81920 },
    };

        j = sizeof(people) / sizeof(people[0]);     /* count of elements */
```

gives j = 3 here, i.e, no of elements in the array; always even if you add or reduce the elements...

But

```
         char b[8];
         i = sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);
```

gives the value of i = a constant = 4 on my machine.

Now thats justified as the sizeof(char*) is constant on my machine and the sizeof(char) too is constant..

But as soon as I declare the struct person, the sizeof(person*) and sizeof(person) should also be constant, and it should also yield a constant value, isn't it???

Comment: I don't believe that the `char` variant always gives you 4... (http://ideone.com/eeniL)

Comment: it gives 4 on my machine, I executed the code. The sizeof(char*) depends on the bytes needed to accommodate an address on my machine and sizeof(char) is 1 always, isn't it. So, It needs 4*sizeof(char) to accommodate an address on my machine...

Comment: This post is an excellent example of why people should post complete programs and not code fragments. Please post the shortest complete program that demonstrates your question. http://sscce.org

Comment: But in the code above, you haven't got a `char*`, you have a `char[8]`.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: My compiler did something strange, I tried the code with Microsoft Visual C++ and it works..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your compiler is wrong.

```
char b[8];
i = sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);
```

should yield `i==8`.

The result you're getting for the `struct` size is correct. I would switch compilers if I were you.

If you were to pass `b` to a function calculating the size, than you'd be right. But as the code is now, no.

Also, if it was a function calculating `sizeof(people) / sizeof(people[0])` which received `people` as a parameter, you'd also get a constant.

This is because arrays decay to pointers when passed as arguments.

Comment: I tried the code with Microsoft Visual C++ and its working now, thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you're actually applying `sizeof` to an array, not a pointer?

In a case like this, the function argument is actually a pointer, so you'll get `i == sizeof(char*)`:

```
void f(char b[8]) {
    i = sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);
}
```

The code you've posted should definitely give the number of array elements. If it doesn't, then you've either got something else very strange in your code, or your compiler is hopelessly broken.

Answer (score 1):

```
  char b[8];          
  i = sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);
```

This should give a value of 8 only. sizeof(b) will give the size of the array and not sizeof(char *) as perceived by you.